# How to bring back the focus to combo box in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, model-view-controller, model

I am trying to change the items of a combo box using up/down arrow key.

The scenarios is that my combo-box is disabling based on some condition and once the conditions is fulfilled, it is enabling.

The problem is that the focus on combo box is lost after it gets enabled.

Here is my View.xaml code :

```xml
    <StackPanel Margin="2.5">
        <Label Content="{x:Static local:StringResources.LBL_FILL_LOC}" Target=" 
        {Binding ElementName=CboFillLoc}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CboFillLoc" IsEnabled="{Binding IsComboEnabled}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
         SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="2.5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And here is the place where combo box is getting enabled (ViewModel.cs)

```
    private async void FetchItems()
        {
            try
            {
                 do something
            }
            catch
            {
        
            }
            finally
            {
                 SearchStatus = StringResources.LBL_READY;
                 ItemsLoading = false;
                 IsComboEnabled = true;
            }
        
        }
```

Here's what I tried in view.xaml:

```xml
    <StackPanel Margin="2.5">
        <Label Content="{x:Static local:StringResources.LBL_FILL_LOC}" Target=" 
        {Binding ElementName=CboFillLoc}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CboFillLoc" IsEnabled="{Binding IsComboEnabled}"
         Focusable="{Binding IsFocusable}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
         SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="2.5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

and in ViewModel.cs I declared this and binded it to focusable property

```
     public bool IsFocused
            {
                get => _isFocused;
                set
                {
                    if (_isFocused == value) return;
                    _isFocused = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsFocused");
                }
            }
```

and here I am trying to get the focus to combo box

```
    private async void FetchItems()
        {
            try
            {
                 do something
            }
            catch
            {
        
            }
            finally
            {
                 SearchStatus = StringResources.LBL_READY;
                 ItemsLoading = false;
                 IsComboEnabled = true;
                 IsFocusable = true;
            }
        
        }
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post code and not images.

Comment: Is this the reason I am getting -ve votes on my question? I am not very frequent on stackoverflow so was unaware of the these.

Comment: In general if you have code that fails, you should provide a minimal running example that reproduces the issue. Don't expect  people to sit down and type the code from your images in case they want to test it. See my answer: you can copy&paste it. Or should I rather post an image of code? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger instead of a binding:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox">
  <ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox}" />
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComboEnabled}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Side note: `Focusable` means exactly that: the element is focusable. It does not mean focused.